# Tensorflow float64 error while running in eager execution

Tags: python, tensorflow, eager-execution

I'm using TF 2.13.0 and I'm getting an error only when eager execution is enabled. Is there a workaround?

The error is

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: TensorArray dtype is float64 but Op is trying to write dtype float32
```

The code is

```
import tensorflow as tf

# when the next line is uncommented, we get an error
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)

@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=None,dtype=tf.float64)])
def TrySine(dev):
    mytensor = tf.map_fn(fn=lambda t,dev=dev: tf.math.sin(dev*3.14/180.0), elems=tf.ones(shape=(8,),dtype='float64'))
    return mytensor


output = TrySine(dev=5.0)

print(output)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, `tensorflow` doesn't like calculations with different `dtypes`. It will typically either throw warnings or errors.

Unless you have a solid reason for using `float64`, I suggest you stick to `float32`, as is the standard in deep learning.

```
import tensorflow as tf

# when the next line is uncommented, we get an error
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)


@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=None,dtype=tf.float32)])
def TrySine(dev):
    mytensor = tf.map_fn(fn=lambda t,dev=dev: tf.math.sin(dev*3.14/180.0), elems=tf.ones(shape=(8,),dtype='float32'))
    return mytensor


output = TrySine(dev=5.0)

print(output)
```

But if you really want to use `float64`, you can make sure your input constant is in this `dtype`:

```
@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec(shape=None,dtype=tf.float64)])
def TrySine(dev):
    mytensor = tf.map_fn(fn=lambda t,dev=dev: tf.math.sin(dev*3.14/180.0), elems=tf.ones(shape=(8,),dtype='float64'))
    return mytensor


output = TrySine(dev=tf.constant(0.5, dtype=tf.float64))

print(output)
```

Comment: We're trying to build a scientific application (solving a partial differential equation) with TensorFlow - and in that field the standard is 64-bit floats for reasons of accuracy and stability. Hence the 64-bit floats.

Comment: I see. In that case you can just convert your input to the function to `float64` like this: `tf.constant(0.5, dtype=tf.float64)`

Comment: Thanks. I'll do that. For some reason, I thought the @tf.function with arguments specified would convert float32 to float64, but that's not the case.